# View of a binary tree from 45 degree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal

So I am not asking diagonal view of a tree, which fortunately I already know. I am asking if I view a tree from 45-degree angle only a few nodes should be visible. So there is a plane which at an angle of 45-degrees from the x-axis. so we need to print all the nodes which are visible from that plane.

For example:

```
            1
          /    \
          2      3
        /  \    /  \
       4   5   6    7
```

So if I look from that plane, I will only see nodes [4, 6, 7] as 5 and 6 overlaps each other. If I add another node at 6, now it will hide 7. How to do that? I searched on internet but couldn't find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an abstract answer as the question is not language specific.

The problem with logging trees like this is the use of recursion.

By that I mean the traversal is going down nodes and up nodes.

What if you wrote a height helper which would return the depth of the current node.

For each depth level, you place the value in an array.

Then, write the values of the array.

Then you could grab the length of the last array and determine the amount of spaces each node needs.

Allow the arrays to hold empty values or else you will have to keep track of which nodes dont have children.

```
int total_depth = tree.getTotalHeight();
int arr[total_depth] = {};
for(int i = total_depth; i--;){
   // there is a formula for the max number of nodes at a given depth of a binary tree
   arr[i] = int arr[maximum_nodes_at_depth]
}
tree.inorderTraverse(function(node){
    int depth = node.getHeightHelper();
    // check if item is null
    if( node!=nullptr && node.Item != NULL)
    {
        arr[depth].push(node.Item)
    }
    else
    {
        arr[depth].push(NULL)    
    }
})
```

So now you would have to calculate the size of your tree and then dynamically calculate how many spaces should prefix each node. The lower the depth the more prefixed spaces to center it.

I apologize but the pseudocode is a mix of javascript and c++ syntax.... which should never happen lol